# Espaço em branco indesejado dando vida a barra de scroll horizontal ao diminuir a tela

Tags: html, css, grid

Ao redimensionar a tela, chega uma hora que um espaço em branco vai sendo gerado no canto da tela, to começando a fazer algo com grid e tentando deixar isso responsivo, devo adicionar media queries pra resolver esse problema ou é algo que devo mudar no código mesmo?

obs: adicionei overflow-x: hidden e o scroll horizontal sumiu mas me pareceu mais um "hack"...

Réplica do código: https://codepen.io/utamo/pen/KJPNdL

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

/* Grid geral */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100vh repeat(3,100vh) 10vh;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header"
        ". midcontent ."
        ". aftermid . "
        ". finalcontent ."
        "footer footer footer"

}
/* Propriedades header */
.landing-header {
    grid-area: header;
    background: url(https://blog.sakugabooru.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/miabyss1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-shrink: 1;
   
}
.landing-text {
    font-size: 10em;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="grid-container">
        <header class="landing-header">
            <h1 class="landing-text">WaifuLounge</h1>
        </header>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que vc está usando um valor fixo no texto, e como esse texto não fica responsivo ele acaba extrapolando os limites do Grid.

Veja que colocando um `word-break: break-all;` no texto já impediria isso, mas acredito que vc não quer que a linha quebre no meio da palavra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Então outra alternativa bem simples é colocar a medida do texto em `VW`, assim ele fica relativo a largura do `viewport` e vai se redimensionar sozinho, sem precisar de *media querys* Mas caso queira tb pode fazer seus `@media` para tratar o texto, mesmo estando em `VW` ou `EM`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código referente a segunda imagem:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

/* Grid geral */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;m
    grid-template-rows: 100vh repeat(3,100vh) 10vh;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header"
        ". midcontent ."
        ". aftermid . "
        ". finalcontent ."
        "footer footer footer"

}
/* Propriedades header */
.landing-header {
    grid-area: header;
    background: url('https://blog.sakugabooru.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/miabyss1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-shrink: 1;
   
}
.landing-text {
    /* aqui vc coloca o tamanho do texto relativo a largura da tela */
    font-size: 13vw;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-container">
    <header class="landing-header">
        <h1 class="landing-text">WaifuLounge</h1>
    </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Valeu bro! terminei esse pequeno site "responsivo" usando vw com o flexbox, se quiser dar uma olhada: 
https://utamo.github.io/waifuReboot/  
Os textos ficavam menores que o esperado mas fui tratando com media queries

Comment: @utm massa! Ficou bem responsivo!